# Read Image pixels, row by row

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I've been working on a project that requires my code to get pixel data of an image and reconstruct it (in another form) however when I try to create an image using the pixel data, it turns out that all the pixels are on the same row.

Here's my code

```py
pixels = (image.getdata())

img_array = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(img_array)
img.save('testrgb.png')
```

How do I read the image's pixels line by line and arrange them in different lists depending on their rows?

**EDIT** I was able to achieve the desired result by using the following code

```py
pixels = list(image.getdata())
print(pixels[0][0])
pixels2 = []
for i in range(0, height):
    pixels2.append(pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width])

#for pixel_value in pixels:
    #print(pixel_value)

img_array = array = np.array(pixels2, dtype=np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(array)
img.save('maps/testrgb.png')
```

Comment: you can divide img_array by image wigth

Comment: it raises an error about how I can't write a png image like that

Comment: Please see my answer below to get a NumPy array representation of the image itself instead the flattened pixels. Can you provide more details on the desired lists? I'd add some more code on that.

Comment: what about taking dimensions of image and iterate through it?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation on [`getdata`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata):

> Returns the contents of this image as a sequence object containing pixel values. The sequence object is flattened, so that values for line one follow directly after the values of line zero, and so on.

If you want to have a NumPy array representation of the actual image, use `np.array` on `image` directly:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image with Pillow
image = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')

# Convert Pillow image to NumPy array
img_array = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)

# ... do some operation on NumPy array (copy rows to lists, etc.) ...

# Convert NumPy array back to Pillow image
img = Image.fromarray(img_array)

# Save image with Pillow
img.save('testrgb.png')
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
Pillow:      7.0.0
----------------------------------------
```